# O´Neill Elementary Differential Geometry. Shape Operators. Section 5. Exercise 9.

Tags: differential-geometry

I am self studying Elementary Differential Geometry by Barret O´Neill. I am stuck in the exercise 9 of section 5:
If $V$ is a tangent vector field on $M$ (with unit normal $U$), then $S(V)$ is the tangent vector field on $M$ whose value at each point **p** is $S_p(V(p))$. Show that if $W$ is also tangent to $M$, then

$S(V) \cdot W =  \nabla_V W\cdot U$

**Definitions:**

1. $S_p(V(p))=-\nabla_{V(p)}U$

2. To define $\nabla_{V(p)}U$ write $U$ in terms of the natural frame field of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by
   $U=\Sigma z_iU_i$.

Then $\nabla_{V(p)}U=\Sigma V(p)[z_i]U_i$, where V(p)[z_i] denotes directional derivative.

**Remark**

I just applied definitions in both sides of the equation but i don´t see why they are equal.

I would appreciate a lot if some one could help me with detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**: Note that $U\cdot W = 0$, and so $\nabla_V(U\cdot W) = 0$. Now use the product rule.

Comment: Oh that´s a nice idea, but the domain of $\nabla_V$ are vectors, and $U\cdot W$ gives real numbers in this case. However, following your nice idea, i think the correct arguments are as follows:

$U\cdot W=0$, and so $0=V(p)[U\cdot W]=\nabla_{V_p}U\cdot W(p)+U(p)\cdot\nabla_{V_p}W=
-S(V)\cdot W+U\cdot\nabla_{V}W$

What do you think? Or maybe, that´s why you posted it as a hint.

Comment: Yes, I do not know the notation of the book. Covariant derivatives can in general be computed of any tensor field, including scalar functions.

Comment: Oooh that sounds complexly interesting. On the other hand, i thank you a lot for taking your time reading and answering my question. Self studying some times gets difficult and don´t know if you are really understanding. So sites like this one are so amazing and of course people like you who takes the time to contribute. Again thanks a lot.

Comment: You’re welcome. You might also find my differential geometry text (freely downloadable at the link in my profile) a helpful alternative source.